# Altering and showing uploaded image in Dash app

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I'm new to Dash apps. I'm interested in creating a web app where the user uploads their own image, and then I alter it in some way, and show the resulting image (ideally using pillow v 6.0.0). A basic example would be to take in an image, rotate it, and show the rotated image. I've been using this [example](https://dash.plotly.com/dash-core-components/upload) as a template for uploading an image and showing the same image. How can I alter the example to rotate the image rather than just displaying the same image?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Sorry, wasn't too clear on that (long day). Edited the question.

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this?

Comment: Yeah, I figured  it out. Just  a matter of taking the base64 string dash returns, converting it into a png, then using PIL to turn the png into an Image object, then rotating the image or whatever you want  to do, then turning the Image object back into png, then back into base64 and displaying that new image